# User friendly URLs in struts2

Tags: java, struts, tomcat6

My project uses both struts1 and struts2 frameworks, I need to change the URLs user friendly. Is there any plugins to remove the .action and .do extension from the urls..?

Please attach the links of documentation along with the comments. 
Thanks In advance.

Comment: There're separate solutions for this with different versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the action extension in struts 2 by adding

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=".foo"/>
```

to the `struts.xml` file (or the properties file etc.)

To remove it give an empty value.

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""/>
```

Resources : http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/strutsproperties.html

But the extensions shouldn't worry you too much unless you are designing a website where users will access the web pages by URL.

For a normal web application I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Hi Thihara....Thanks for your response.. However I cannot find struts.action.extension in my struts.xml and i dont have a struts.properties file...shall i add a properties file....How to configure it....?

Comment: It won't be there. It's in the struts.properties file. You are overriding it in the struts.xml file by adding it.

Comment: I have added a new struts.properties and it is configured, But still now if i give the value as  struts.action.extension=action,, to "", then when i try to acess that page, it says Action or result not found. Is there any other file I have to change the configuratuion...?